# Status is disabled for my Netflix API Key / Application

Tags: api, netflix

I know just recently Netflix [announced they are longer issue new public API developer keys](http://developer.netflix.com/blog/read/Changes_to_the_Public_API_Program) however I got my key two months ago for a proof of concept project in development.

I just started working on implementing Netflix API data and noticed in my account / application info that the status is disabled.

Any calls I make to the API return a '403 Developer Inactive' response.

I just emailed publicapi[at]netflix.com to see if they can enable it but also thought I should see if anyone has any info here as Netflix has recommended 'developers to continue their conversations at StackOverflow with the tag “netflixapi”'.

Any information would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Same here. My app ran for years but with very little usage so I guess it's not considered active by their criteria. I emailed publicapi@netflix.com about a month ago. I have not received a response.

Comment: Too bad Netflix is forcing us to scrape their website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't answer emails so save your time. They will not issue or reactivate existing keys.

Comment: Yeah, I even connected with someone I knew internally.